# How to prove if a function is well-defined?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, congruences

I've been trying hard over this problem and I am unable to understand the exact technique to solve this problem. I've tried referring to the notes of my class but it seems that I might not have written it in my notes. The significant problem is to not know where and how to start.

If somebody can hint me a start then I think I might be able to solve this on my own. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks  [Here's the problem in the image in this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Z8r.png)

[image]

Comment: Remember, $\mathbb Z_6$ isn't just the six numbers $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$; rather, it is a collection of six infinite equivalence classes. You have to show that the definition doesn't depend on which $x$ you choose to represent the equivalence class. For example, $[1]$, $[7]$, and $[13]$ are the same equivalence classes, even though $1$, $7$, and $13$ are different representatives of it. It may help to note that, for this specific equivalence class, all representatives are of the form $1+6k$ (where $k\in \mathbb Z$), and there are no others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove that a function of equivalence classes is well defined, you need to prove that for any two coset representatives, the value of the function applied to each is the same.